# Meltdown and Spectre protection for Ubuntu 14.04.5 (Kernel 4.4)?

Tags: 14.04, security, lts, vulnerability

Does an installation running on 14.04.5 (Kernel 4.4) need to be patched according to USN-3540-2?

I received contradictory informations. Some saying that as it is a LTS version, it already includes protection to meltdown and spectre vulnerabilities and it does not have to be patched. Is that right?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The mitigation fixes for these two specific sets of attacks are not limited to the kernel, however if you are up to date with security patches from Ubuntu, then yes, you already have the patches. You also need updated `intel-microcode` package for example, for some of the fix. There was also a Firefox update for mitigation of Spectre attacks in the browser.

You can see the publishing history for 4.4 kernel updates [on launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/linux-lts-xenial) as well.